# How run a oracle qry and get the results to a list variable

Tags: c#, webmethod

```
ClsRowCollection location = connection.ReadOperation(ClsQueryManager.SELECT_PRODUCTNAME_LOCATION, new string[] { lotInvList[i].ToUpper().Trim() });
```

Query used:

```
Select location,Qty from ProductTbl where number = :param0
```

I need to get values Location and Qty and pass to a list.

Comment: What is `ClsRowCollection`? What is `connection`?

Comment: is a class used to :ClsRowCollection
    private const string MODULE = "ClsRowCollection:";
    private List<ClsColumn> _row = new List<ClsColumn>();
      /// Returns column collection 
     /// This method adds a collumn
    /// This method return the row in a position.
   /// This method return the size of the collection.
  /// This method verifies if the collection is empty.
    I can't add oart of the code is a little long